# how to dispay today's date in tale cell? i am able to retrieve date only for one cell i want today date for all the column

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a table column as today where I should view today day.
my code:

```
<td id="demo"></td>
<script>
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

here in this only one cell is getting today's date and remaining cells display blank.

```
<td id="demo2"></td>
<script>
document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

when I tried with different demo like below seperate demo for each cell then all the cells are displaying dates.

but how to display today's date in all cells  with a ingle javascript? Please help.

Comment: What you mean by `when I tried with different demo like below separate demo for each cell then all the cells are displaying dates.`

Comment: @brk OP has a table, and they want to populate a column with the current date, without adding an id to every cell on the column and separate scripts to change the content of the said cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Get all the columns HTMLElements using `document.querySelectorAll` and then apply innerHTML for each HTMLElement.

```js
var allDateCols = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable .dateCol");

for(let col of allDateCols){
  col.innerHTML = new Date();
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td class="dateCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td class="dateCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td class="dateCol"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashvin777. Its working.
can you please help in, I want to display only date like "7/21/2017" not as "Fri Jul 21 2017 12:58:49 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tick the answer as well